# MongoDB returns empty on find() but content on findOne or when using count()

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using mongoDB for a new project at work and I got into some troubles which I can't find any solutions for. I have a model in my project which contains a method to fetch some data from MongoDB, which works just fine as long as I use findOne() instead of find().

The method:

```
public function getData($input) {

        $output = $this->_collection->find($input);
        //$output = $this->_collection->findOne($input);
        Zend_Debug::Dump($output);
        return $output;
    }
```

When running that piece of code I get this from the dump:

```
object(MongoCursor)#52 (0) {
}
```

Using findOne() :

```
array(12) {
  ["_id"] => object(MongoId)#54 (1) {
    ["$id"] => string(24) "4fd85d178efd307080000001"
  }
  ["autoadd"] => string(1) "1"
  ["name"] => string(5) "Sport"
  ["keyword"] => string(8) "cookie29"
  ["antal"] => string(1) "0"
  ["antal_week_date"] => string(10) "1218818007"
  ["version"] => string(1) "1"
  ["active"] => string(1) "1"
  ["antal_week"] => string(1) "0"
  ["customer_id"] => string(1) "2"
  ["id"] => string(2) "29"
  ["insert_date"] => string(10) "2007-11-21"
}
```

And when using `$output = $this->_collection->find($input)->count();`:

```
int(20)
```

What am I doing wrong? This might be a simple problem, but I can't find any other way to do this stuff. If you wonder what the input is, it's just an associative array:

```
$data = array('active' => '1');
```

Please help me fetch all those 20 nice "rows" of data.
I'd be grateful.

Thanks for your advice and better wisdom!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`find()` returns cursor, not the array with actual data. You have to iterate the cursor. This is [an example from the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php)

```
$m = new Mongo();
$db = $m->selectDB('test');
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'phpmanual');

// search for documents where 5 < x < 20
$rangeQuery = array('x' => array( '$gt' => 5, '$lt' => 20 ));

$cursor = $collection->find($rangeQuery);
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
    var_dump($doc);
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I thought I had done something very wrong.
Just got surprised since findOne didn't return a cursor and where I was reading: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.queries.php I didn't find any examples as from your link.

Thanks.

Comment: This is uncommon funcitonality to PHP and a few other drivers only. In other languages a cursor is returned even on a findOne() however the PHP driver does the middle step for you and gets the first record from the cursor and returns it as an assoc array. If you look up MongoCursor in the docs you will see it has methods and examples of getting data from it.

Comment: @Sammaye: Can you specify languages where `findOne` returns cursor? Even mongo shell returns a document, no cursor.

Comment: I cannot since I only use PHP and JS and a few others however if you search mongodb-user you will find mentions of such behaviour in other language like go

Comment: Things may have changed and all drivers may be upto date with findOne now however I am not going to bet my money on that statement.